# Los Angeles county aerial imagery

Tags: coordinate-system, data, united-states, basemap

I am looking for a basemap of LA county showing aerial imagery similar to Google Earth. However, I also need it in a specific projection: NAD_1983_StatePlane_California_V_FIPS_0405_Feet.

Does anyone know where I can find such a basemap?

I can't seem to find it in California's GIS database

Comment: try http://egis3.lacounty.gov/dataportal/2015/11/24/naip-national-agriculture-imagery-program-imagery/

Answer (score 2):

Socalgis.org is your best bet to find it..

https://socalgis.org/?s=NAIP&submit=Search